# error: initializer element is not constant (how can I implement this?)

Tags: c, function, time, compiler-errors

I understand that I'm getting the `initializer element is not constant` error because I try to assign a call to `clock()` to a `startTime` inside `Timer` and `startTime` is static (which means it's value can only be something that's known at compile-time).

Here's my code, I need to call `(*func)` every `seconds` seconds and am unsure how to implement this, so what would be a good way of doing what I need?

```
static void Timer(void (*func)(void), int seconds)
{       
        static clock_t startTime = clock();

        if ((startTime - clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) > seconds)
        {
            startTime = clock();
            (*func)();
        }
}
```

## Update

The people who commented suggestted that I do something like this, but if I do this the `if` at the beginning is redundant:

```
    static clock_t startTime = (clock_t) -1;

    if (startTime == -1) startTime = clock();
    else if ((startTime - clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) > seconds)
    {
        startTime = clock();
        (*func)();
    }
```

Comment: You can't do *initialization* with a value that is not a compile-time constant, but you *can* assign to it.

Comment: Read up on the static keyword. It does not restrict dynamic changes of the variables it is used for. It is more about the life time of a variable, especially across calls to the function. Also, I agree with @EOF. Split the definition of the static variable from the assignment. Then it will accept return values of runtime calls to functions. I assume that you did not try to make it only be called once.

Comment: One way: `static clock_t startTime =  (clock_t) -1; if (startTime == -1) startTime = clock(); else if ((startTime - clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) > seconds) { /* your original code */ }`

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Timer(void (*func)(void), int seconds)
{       
    static clock_t startTime = 0;

    if(!startTime)
        startTime = clock();

    if ((startTime - clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) > seconds)
    {
        startTime = clock();
        (*func)();
    }
}
```